# Patch Panel Cable Tangle

Tags: patch-management, cable-management, networking

Possibly the noob-est question ever (I'm a developer stepping in to do some sysadmin stuff):

I have a 48-port patch panel bolted to a wall about 10 feet from where my rack is.

Right now there's a bundle of ~26 ethernet cables going from the patch panel to the rack, which seems kind of crazy to me (just dangles in the air at about 4-6').

What are my options with something like this?  It seems like maybe I should put the patch panel in the rack directly and then run the cable directly from the ceiling into the rack?  This would limit how much I could move the rack around, but that's not a huge issue right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a problem, leave it.

If it is a problem (cable management, C-level types walking through, etc.) then buy an [overhead cable tray](http://www.panduit.com/Products/ProductOverviews/OverheadUnderfloorCableRouting/index.htm) and use that to create a run from your patch panel to your rack.

Answer (score 2):

There are wire trays available that you can run from the top of the rack to the wall.  They can be suspended from the ceiling so the rack isn't restricted.  Having the patch panel in the rack is not a bad idea or you could mount the switch right in the rack and only send the uplink out of the rack.

Lots of possibilities here.